# Last child component rendering iframe even though parent component has been 'reloaded'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So I have a component (the parent) called Tools, and its job is to grab the id passed into the URL and then get the correct toolComponent using this id and then simply display that component.

So the child components that I am trying to display each have an iframe in them which are all hardcoded so no props.

When the Tool component renders for the very first time, it works fine and shows that child toolComponent. But then I click a link which passes in a new id into the URL and attempts to load this new component, BUT it fails to load. I get an error saying it can't find the elementById, but this error is inside the last child components source code. Meaning, when I go to the new tool, its still attempting to show the old child component and not the new one.

I have put print statements on two toolComponents and have gone back and forth between them and the weird thing is, while loading the new tool, it is printing statements that come from both the new and old tool (child component). However, after I get this error then I manually refresh and all is good again.

Here is the parent component:

```
const Tool = ({
  getContent,
  closeContent,
  content: {
   content,
   loading,
   contents
  },
  user,
  match,
 }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
 
  useEffect(() => {
   scrollToTop();
   getContent(match.params.id);
   console.log("got content");
   return () => {
    logView(user, match.params.id, "tool");
    closeContent();
    console.log("closed content");
    // history.go();
   };
  }, [getContent, closeContent, match.params.id, user]);
 
  let ToolComponent;
 
  const listItemStyle = {
   paddingTop: "40px",
   paddingBottom: "40px"
  };
 
  return loading || content === null ? ( <
   Spinner / >
  ) : ( 
    (ToolComponent = getTool(content.content_id.path))
    <ToolComponent />
  );
 };
```

Also, I have in there history.go() but I have it commented out. `history.go()` actually fixes the problem but I feel like this isn't the best approach or do you think this is okay to do?